# Two or more applications authenticate by OAuth2

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I have two Spring applicatons and I need to authenticate first application in another apllication. Its server-to-server communication and authentication. Is OAuth suitable for this or there is another way to rosolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, OAuth 2.0 is suitable for authenticating other applications (clients) with its Authorization Server.

OAuth 2.0 Client Credentials grant type does that. For more information Check out these links: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4 and https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/client-credentials/

Spring provides an API ([OAuth2RestTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/OAuth2RestTemplate.html)) to automate client authentication process.